# How can i handle popups in playwright-java?

Tags: webautomation, playwright

**How can i handle alerts and popups in playwright-java?**
there are different methods in API like page.onDialog(), page.onPopup(), what is the difference between them and how can i generate a handle?

```
//code to launch my browser and url
            Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
            Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new LaunchOptions().withHeadless(false).withSlowMo(50));
            BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
            Page page = context.newPage();
            page.navigate("http://myurl.com");
    
//had to switch to iframe to click on upload button
            Frame mypage = page.frameByName("uploadScreenPage");
    
//below line is triggering the alert
            mypage.setInputFiles("//*[@id='fileUpload']",Path.of("C:\\myFile.jar"));
            
//using this code to handle alert, which is not working
            page.onDialog(dialog -> {dialog.accept();});
```

unable to accept alert using the above code. also alert has occurred after clicking an element that is inside an iframe. how can i handle such alerts?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dialog`s are messages like an [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) or a [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), whereas `popup`s are new pages, like the one you would get by calling [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

This is how you can use it :

```
page.onDialog(dialog -> {
    assertEquals("alert", dialog.type());
    assertEquals("", dialog.defaultValue());
    assertEquals("yo", dialog.message());
    dialog.accept();
});
page.evaluate("alert('yo')");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have edited the question with the exact scenario. do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to answer this question. I encountered the same situation and find the solution. Please see below:

//Handling Pop-up or new page

```
Page pgdriver1 = pagedriver.waitForPopup(new Runnable()
{
        public void run() {
        pagedriver.click("text=\"Analiza\""); 
        }
    });

pgdriver1.click("//button[normalize-space(@aria-label)=\"Close dialog\"]/nx-icon");
```

I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
//listening to the alert
page.onDialog(dialog -> {dialog.accept();});

//next line will be action that triggers your alert
page.click("//['clickonsomethingthatopensalert']")
```

Comment: You need to explain what is the problem and how your answer address the question. Just pasting the code is not an answer.